# Fatal error : grub installation /dev/SDA failed

Tags: grub2, system-installation, uefi

I am trying to install Ubuntu from past 3 days and constantly getting the above mentioned error.
I have windows 10 with UEFI and want to dual boot it with windows using Ubuntu image in USB.
For the first time it installed properly but *efibootmgr* was not able to detect Ubuntu so I was not able to change boot preference. So I deleted the partition and again created the partition and booted into Ubuntu.
Since then I'm getting that error.
Please help me.

Answer (score -1):

You have to install grub into /dev/sda2 as it is the ESP where bootloder belong in UEFI boot.

Why? on preinstalled windows 10 there is following partion created befor installing linux for the firtst time:

- 300 MiB restore
- 100 MiB ESP (needs the mount point /boot/EFI in the system later)
- most of the disk windows C
- optional windows D for data, videos programs, document stiff like that

so to install grub rigt you have to install it on sda2.

`sudo grub-install [options] /dev/sda2`

see `grub-install --help` for details for options. Also `man 8 grub` for more details on grub or the [grub Manual online](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html) here.

Comment: This machine came with windows 8 and I have upgraded it to 10. @kupferdrache

Comment: Can you please tell me the process?

Comment: Which point do you need intructions for?

Comment: How do I get the installing path for grub to sda2?
According to gparted the 50 gb partition that i have created is sda4.

Comment: I edit the answer this may take while to get approved. here a preview: issue `grub-install --help`to see the documenation.

Comment: Again I see another answer from you that lack the information of how to actually do what you suggest, how do you install grub to that partition? Also, how do you know it is sda2? You don't, OP said sda4. If you answer you MUST include the steps to achieve your suggestion, or that is all it is, a suggestion and that is what comments are for. -1

Comment: because the esp is the second partion of the first disk on preinstalled windows computers, I believe you want to troll me @MarkKirby.

Comment: Troll you? Check my profile, I am no troll. I am advising you on how to make your answers fit our quality standards. Answers that make suggestions but do not cover how to achieve that, do not meat the quality standard.

Comment: @Mark Kirby can you please explain it?I tried using that command but it says cannot find path to '/cow'.

Comment: Sda2 = EFI system partition. Sda8 - ext4 and sda9 -Linux swap. Now please tell me what am I supposed to do? I urgently need ubuntu for my college project @MarkKirby

Comment: @Kupferdrache I'm also getting some Libparted warning stating "The driver descriptor says the physical block size is 2048 bytes, but Linux says it is 512 bytes."

Comment: you can Ignore that warning for now. it is not important for you. It looks like you have to edit your grub.cfg files. but not sure, what @MarkKirby told you to do.

Comment: @Kupferdrache He didn't told me anything to do.